# On the localized screening of cerium (when compared to iron)

Tags: quantum-chemistry

I was reading the paper 'A linear response approach to the calculation of the effective interaction parameters in the LDA+U method' by Cococcioni - ([Paper here)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0405160.pdf) .

Quoting from the first paragraph on page 9, '**The screening in metallic cerium is extremely localized..**'. Even though this section deals with the calculation of the Hubbard 'U' (which might be more appropriate for a physics forum), the underlying chemistry is still intact, I understand. But I can't reconcile this from a chemistry point of view. To furnish more context, the authors compare the results of metallic cerium with metallic ion (from the previous section in the paper).

To recapitulate, the assertion here is that the screening in metallic cerium is extremely localized when compared to metallic iron. I know this is directly related to the electronic configuration, but I would be happy if someone would be able to provide an explanation for this.

PS: I added a bounty and even though it says 'answer required from reputable source', I will accept any detailed answer that solves the ambiguity, even if you don't cite or refer any sources.